# How to keep CollectionView scrolled to bottom always in .Net MAUI

Tags: maui, observablecollection

I want to create a Log window using **CollectionView**. Whenever a new item is added, it should automatically scroll to the bottom. I attempted to implement this functionality using a **behavior** for easy code portability. Here's how I wrote the behavior:

```
namespace Behaviors;


public class ScrollToBottomBehavior
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty DataSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.CreateAttached("DataSource",
                                        typeof(object),
                                        typeof(ScrollToBottomBehavior),
                                        null,
                                        BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                        propertyChanged: OnDataSourceChanged);

    public static int GetDataSource(BindableObject view) => (int)view.GetValue(DataSourceProperty);

    public static void SetDataSource(BindableObject view, int value) => view.SetValue(DataSourceProperty, value);

    private static void OnDataSourceChanged(BindableObject sender, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (sender is not CollectionView view) return;
        //ObservableCollection<object> collection = newValue as ObservableCollection<object>;
        if (newValue is not ObservableCollection<object> collection) return;
        //view?.ScrollTo(collection.LastOrDefault(), null, ScrollToPosition.End);
        view?.ScrollTo(collection.Count - 1, position: ScrollToPosition.End);
    }
}
```

However, I failed because the **Add** method of **ObservableCollection** does not trigger the **PropertyChanged** event.

I also tried manually setting the **SelectedItem** to the last item of the **ObservableCollection** every time an item was added, but this didn't make the **CollectionView** scroll to the bottom automatically.

I have a couple of ideas:

1. Modify the **ObservableCollection** to notify on **Add**, or
2. Modify the **CollectionView** to add a **ScrollToBottom** property, as shown below, but I still encountered failure.

```
internal class CollectionViewExtended : CollectionView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ScrollToButtomProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ScrollToButtom), typeof(bool), typeof(CollectionViewExtended), false);

    public bool ScrollToButtom
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(ScrollToButtomProperty);
        set => SetValue(ScrollToButtomProperty, value);
    }

    protected override void OnChildAdded(Element child)
    {
        base.OnChildAdded(child);
        if (ScrollToButtom)
        {
            ScrollTo(child, position: ScrollToPosition.End, animate: true);
        }
    }

}
```

Any sugguestions will be thankful.

Comment: Did you try manually setting `SelectedItem` *and* catching the `SelectionChanged` event to scroll the CollectionView?

Comment: `ObservableCollection` should fire a `CollectionChanged` event when an item is added

Comment: @RiccardoMinato I'll try this now. But It doesn't look very elegant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CollectionView` defines a `ItemsUpdatingScrollMode` property, which is backed by a bindable property. This property gets or sets a `ItemsUpdatingScrollMode` enumeration value that represents the scrolling behavior of the `CollectionView` when new items are added to it. The `ItemsUpdatingScrollMode` enumeration defines the following members:

- `KeepItemsInView` keeps the first item in the list displayed when new
  items are added.
- `KeepScrollOffset` ensures that the current scroll position is
  maintained when new items are added.
- `KeepLastItemInView` adjusts the scroll offset to keep the last item in
  the list displayed when new items are added.

The default value of the `ItemsUpdatingScrollMode` property is `KeepItemsInView`. Therefore, when new items are added to a CollectionView the first item in the list will remain displayed. To ensure that the last item in the list is displayed when new items are added, set the `ItemsUpdatingScrollMode` property to `KeepLastItemInView`:

```
<CollectionView ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView">
    ...
</CollectionView>
```

For more information, check document: [Control scroll position when new items are added](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/scrolling?view=net-maui-7.0#control-scroll-position-when-new-items-are-added).

**Note:**

In fact, the exact position of the item after the scroll has completed can be specified with the position argument of the `ScrollTo` methods. This argument accepts a `ScrollToPosition` enumeration member.

For more information, check document: [Control scroll position](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/scrolling).

Comment: 1, ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView" seems not work. the scroll bar is still stick to the top of collectionview.

Comment: 2, ScrollTo() results in a flickering window. the view is not smooth if items are added to the ItemSource very quickly. To avoid too many items in CV, I add items like this:             ``` LogData.Add(new LogString(message, level));
            while (LogData.Count > 100)
                LogData.RemoveAt(0);
```

Comment: This is a known issue in [MAUI:CollectionView not scrolling inside a StackLayout or without setting HeightRequest](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8888). As a workaround, you can set a value for `HeightRequest` in `<CollectionView>`.Then set `ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView"`  for `CollectionView` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working for Windows platform - works on Android tested by me - currently as of .NET 7 and "probably" will be fixed by .NET 8 - it got added to the "backlog" but I don't see any confirmation about it being checked or a date to have it fixed
You can check for more information here:

[[Windows] CollectionView ItemsUpdatingScrollMode property not working
#4116](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4116)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in **MAUI:CollectionView** not scrolling inside a StackLayout or without setting HeightRequest.

As a workaround, you can **set a value** for **HeightRequest** in .Then set **ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView"** for CollectionView and try again. –
Asif Hussain-Os

Answer (score -2):

It has been backlog from dotnet5 in xamarin to dotnet8.
Only additional code can be added.

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollView x:name=“sv”>    
    <CollectionView x:name=“CV” MaimumHeightRequest=“{binding Source={x:reference sv},path=Height}>
    ……
    </CollectionView>
    </ScrollView>
    </Grid>

MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=>
{
……
CV.ScrollTo(X,Y,ScrollTOPosition.MakeVisible,true);
……
}
```

They won't fix it for 10 years, I'm sure.
Abandon the use of maui.
Swift development is faster.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).